# Desktop content no longer visible after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

After I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 contents of my desktop directory are no longer displayed on desktop.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

- First make sure that the `Desktop` directory in your home directory contains some files.
- If it does, then install `gnome-tweak-tool`. [image: Install via the software center]
- Run `gnome-tweak-tool`.
- Make sure that *Have file manager handle the desktop* is turned **ON**.

[image]